# Multiple request params with Locale 'language' param

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, http-request-parameters

I'm developing Spring MVC application. I have several locale languages and when I change them on JSP pages which require their own request params, I get an exception like:

```
Required int parameter 'remedyId' is not present
```

The link I used to change locale is:

```
<a href="?language=en">
```

When I click the link, it overrides request parameters in current URL with it's own.

```
http://localhost:8080/medapp/remedyInfo?language=ru
```

Instead of:

```
http://localhost:8080/medapp/remedyInfo?remedyId=1&language=ru
```

I suppose there is syntax to add multiple request parameters to current URL, but I don't know it. Thanks.

Comment: Look at the docs for HttpServletRequest: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html in there you will find how to get the url and the current query string.

Comment: did you get its solution?

Comment: @VikasVats Vats I am afraid no.